# Problemas con ARRAY y FUNCTION en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Hola acudo a ustedes a ver si me dan una mano porque tengo el siguiente error en javascript:

```
TAXESID[1] = 1;
TAXESNAME[1] = "Ninguno";
TAXESISONAME[1] = "Ninguno";
TAXESPORCENT[1] = "0.00";

TAXESID[2] = 2;
TAXESNAME[2] = "Impuesto General a la Venta";
TAXESISONAME[2] = "IGV";
TAXESPORCENT[2] = "18.00";

TAXESID[3] = 3;
TAXESNAME[3] = "Exonerado";
TAXESISONAME[3] = "Exonerado";
TAXESPORCENT[3] = "0.00";


function sumar(fila) {
    cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad[' + fila + ']').value;
    preciounitario = document.getElementById('preciounitario[' + fila + ']').value;
    impuestoid = document.getElementById('impuesto[' + fila + ']').value;
    totalsindescuento = (cantidad * preciounitario);
    preciototal = totalsindescuento;
    preciototal = preciototal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('preciototal[' + fila + ']').value = preciototal;
    descuento.toFixed(2);


    if (impuestoid == 2) {

        pvcigv = preciototal * (1 + (TAXESPORCENT[impuestoid] / 100));
        alert(pvcigv);
    }



}
sumar(1);
```

El problema es jalar el array dentro de la function para que funcione los impuestos, `TAXESPORCENT[impuestoid]` donde `impuestoid` ya esta dado un valor en un input text.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el error que estás teniendo? Al solamente poder leer tu código es muy difícil que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: No se entiende, ni lo que quieres hacer ni tu error.